# Integrating a faction with $e^x$ in the denominator

Tags: integration

Let $I$ be the integral we are asked to evaluate. We have:
$$ I = \int \dfrac{1}{e^x \left( e^{x}+1\right) } \,\, dx $$
Now, I apply the technique of partial fractions.
\begin{align*} 
\dfrac{1}{e^x \left( e^{x}+1\right)} &=
 \dfrac{ A }{e^x+1} + \dfrac{B}{e^x} \\
1 &= A( e^x) + B(e^x+1) \\
\end{align*}
Now, we setup the following system of equations:
\begin{align*} 
A + B &= 0 \\
B  &= 1
\end{align*}
Solving for $A$ we find that $A = -1$.
\begin{align*} 
I &= \int \dfrac{1}{e^x} \,\, dx - \int \dfrac{1}{\left( e^{x}+1\right)} \,\, dx \\
\int \dfrac{1}{e^x} \,\, dx  &= \int e^{-x} \,\, dx \\
\int \dfrac{1}{\left( e^{x}+1\right)} \,\, dx &=
 \int \dfrac{e^x}{\left( e^{2x}+e^x\right)} \,\, dx \\
u &= e^x \\
du &= e^x \, dx \\
\int \dfrac{1}{\left( e^{x}+1\right)} \,\, dx &=
 \int \dfrac{1}{u^2 + u} \,\, du \\
\end{align*}
Now, I apply the technique of partial fractions.
\begin{align*}
\dfrac{1}{u^2 + u}  &= \dfrac{1}{u(u+1)}  \\
\dfrac{1}{u^2 + u} &= \dfrac{ C }{u+1} + \dfrac{D}{u} \\
1 &= Cu + D(u+1) \\
D &= 1 \\
C &= -1 \\
\dfrac{1}{u^2 + u} &= \dfrac{1}{u} - \dfrac{1}{u+1} \\
\int \dfrac{1}{e^x+1} \, dx &=
 \int e^{-x} \, dx  - \int e^{-x+1} \, dx \\
\int \dfrac{1}{e^x+1} \, dx &= -e^{-x} + e^{-x+1} \\
I &= -e^{-x} - \left( -e^{-x} + e^{-x+1}  \right) + C \\
I &= e^{-x+1} + C
\end{align*}
According to an online integral calculator, the answer is:
$$ \ln{\left(  e^x + 1 \right) }  - e^{-x} - x + C$$
Where did I go wrong?

Comment: $1/(u+1) \neq e^{-x+1}$. Also, why did you multiply by $e^x$ after the first partial fractions, when you could have multiplied by $e^{-x}$? This would have saved you a second partial fractions computation and limited your opportunities for error.

Comment: @NinadMunshi Multiplying by $e^{-x}$ would have been the smart thing to do. It leads to a better solution. However, I did not see it until you told me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is in $\int \dfrac{1}{e^x+1} \, dx = -e^{-x} + e^{-x+1}$. In fact you have everything you need to complete the integral correctly: write (as you did) $$\int \dfrac{1}{e^x+1} \, dx = \int \dfrac{1}{u^2+u} \, dx =\int \dfrac{1}{u}- \dfrac{1}{u+1}\, dx=\ln\left|u\right|-\ln\left|u+1\right|=x-\ln\left|e^x+1\right|$$ and you will get the answer given for I.

Answer (score 2):

so I think you over complicated this integrel
just multiblay and divide by $e^{-x}$ and get
$$\int \frac{e^{-x}}{1+e^{-x}}dx=-ln(1+e^{-x})+c=-ln(e^{x}+1)+x+c$$
so the desired integral is
$$ln(e^{x}+1)-x-e^{-x}+C$$